# printing special ascii characters that appear as empty string in matlab

Tags: matlab, ascii

I'm trying to print the NAK char over serial to a device. On putty, I do this with Ctrl+U. However, in matlab I don't think I'm doing this correctly. I tried:

```
fprintf(s,char(21))
```

to no avail.

in matlab, disp(char(21)) shows nothing, what should I be doing?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to look like? Something like this: ␕, i.e., the [visible unicode version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-acknowledge_character)? Matlab's command window doesn't support much - [not even HTML fully](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-matlab-command-window-colors-part2/) - so I'd bet that that you're not likely to get it to display there. Are you sure that it's not sending? Can you send other strings? You have some missing stuff in you command, by the way: `fprintf('%s',char(21))`.